# MongoDB: Get the length of a subfield as part of a query

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb, is there a way to ask for the length of a subfield as part of a query?

Suppose I have a blog_post collection, and each post has fields title and content (both text fields), and a comments field containing a list of comments.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
db.blog_posts.find(
  {_id:ObjectId("4fd69d962fa6cd0a8e00002d")},
  {"title":1, "content": 1, "comments": $length}
)
```

and get back:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fd69d962fa6cd0a8e00002d"),
  "title" : "Curae proin eni",
  "content" : "Etiam lacus euismod litora malesuada tempus a adipiscing mus.",
  "comments" : 27
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return the length of a field using a query in this way, but you can use map reduce to find the length of an array:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

You could also use db.eval() in order to return the length of an array "a" by creating a function that takes _id of a document:
{_id: 1, a : [1, 2, 3]}

```
t = function (id) {
        return db.eval(function (id) {
           var t = db.test.findOne({_id:id});
           var total = t.a.length;
           return total;
        }, 
        id);
    }

t(1) = 3
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using%7B%7Bdb.eval%28%29%7D%7D

You should note, however, that db.eval() is a blocking operation, so for long running jobs, you should use map reduce. Please let me know if this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Although I provided an example using db.eval(), I wouldn't recommend using this function.  db.eval() uses Javascript, which is slow.  It's much better to do this calculation client-side, or to store the length of the array in its own field (which you increment when appending new values to the array).